# Tkinter Python: Exception Handle to display an error message

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling

```
rating_var = IntVar()
rating = int()

def quit():

    newRoot = Toplevel(root)
    newRoot.geometry("750x250")
    newRoot.title = ("QuitBox")
    Label(newRoot, text="Before you go " + name.get() + ", Rate us from 1-10!", font=17).pack()
    quitentry = Entry(newRoot, width=50, textvariable=rating_var)
    quitentry.pack()
    exitButton = Button(newRoot, text="exit", command=quitButton1)
    exitButton.pack()

def quitrating():
    newRoot4 = Toplevel(root)
    newRoot4.geometry("750x250")
    newRoot4.title = ("ErrorBox")
    if rating < 1 or rating > 10:
        Label(newRoot4, text="Please enter a Valid Number")
        closeButton1 = Button(newRoot4, text="try again", command=newRoot4.quit)
        closeButton1.pack()
    else:
        quitButton1()


def quitButton1():

    newRoot3 = Toplevel(root)
    newRoot3.geometry("750x250")
    newRoot3.title = ("ThankyouBox")
    Label(newRoot3, text="Thank you " + name.get() + "!", font=17).pack()
    closeButton = Button(newRoot3, text="close", command=root.quit)
    closeButton.pack()
```

The quit function works and the quitButton function as well the box pops up and Gives the prompt. But the exception handling does not work.

It ignores the quitrating function and just executes the first and last functions. Anything I'm missing or some error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: in quitrating method pass a validation that given input is number so pass the is integer condition, as given ( if rating < 1 or rating > 10 and  rating =! rating.isdigit() : )

Comment: What is this command=root.quit??

Comment: @toyotaSupra root.quit exits the whole program. It just takes the root thats defined in the beginning of the program and quits it.